# Audio over Speaker Jack in Lakka?

Tags: audio, lakka

I cannot seem to get Lakka to output audio to the Speaker Jack.

Lakka sees two audio devices, but both look like the same thing, and neither gives me audio.

> Lakka (community) Version: 2.0
>   Lakka:~ # aplay -L
>   **null**
>       Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
>   **default:CARD=ALSA**
>       bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 ALSA
>       Default Audio Device
>   **sysdefault:CARD=ALSA**
>       bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 ALSA
>       Default Audio Device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Putty to login to your Pie User = root Password = root

At the terminal cmd prompt type

```
nano /storage/.config/autostart.sh
```

This will create a startup file

Inside this file type in

```
amixer cset numid=3 1
```

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit the file then Y to save the file.

Reboot and your sound should now be coming from your audio jack every time you startup Lakka

Answer (score 1):

HDMI to VGA adaptor

If you are using a HDMI to VGA adaptor on a Raspberry Pi 1 or 2 and you want to use the jack output for the sound you have to write in config.txt on the first partition of the SD card:

hdmi_ignore_edid_audio=1

So the board’ll not use the HDMI sound output.

Answer (score 0):

Much like how you do it for Rasbian, the command:

```
amixer cset numid=3 1
```

Will force the audio out the speaker jack.

According to the Lakka documentation we are somewhat limited to how we can enter console commands, with SSH being the easiest.
In Lakka:

> Settings->Services->SSH
>   Information->Network Information (to get the IP Address)

On a connected PC:
in Putty (or similar). Enter the ip address in the host text box. When prompted for username/pass enter root/root.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.