# Set speaker jack in Lakka to default?

Tags: audio, putty, speakers, lakka

I have a small sound issue in Lakka (on the Pi 3 model B+) and was wondering if anyone knows how to fix it. 
Basically, everytime I start Lakka I have no sound using the Speaker jack.

This answer from a couple of years ago works for me:
[Audio over Speaker Jack in Lakka?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68024/audio-over-speaker-jack-in-lakka)

```
amixer cset numid=3 1
```

....but I have to redo the procedure in Putty every time I restart the Pi. 
Anyone knows how to make the change permanent/default? Is that doable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is an option in `/boot/config.txt` or somewhere else that can be set but you have always the possibility to run

```
amixer cset numid=3 1
```

on boot up with a **systemd** unit file.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this command into `.config/autostart.sh` file (.config usually under /storage， also home dir). If it does not exist, create one.

Comment: I think that should be as a `___.desktop` file under `.config/autostart`, although I do not know if the default DE on Raspbian uses that properly (assuming the OP uses Raspbian).  Also, this will only run *if someone logs into a GUI desktop* as that user.

Answer (score 0):

Use Putty to login to your Pie User = root Password = root

At the terminal cmd prompt type

```
nano /storage/.config/autostart.sh
```

This will create a startup file

Inside this file type in

```
amixer cset numid=3 1
```

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> to exit the file then Y to save the file.

Reboot and your sound should now be coming from your audio jack every time you startup Lakka